# f# tools 3.1.1 not working with visual studio web express 2013. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: f#, visual-studio-2013

None of the f# templates I've installed work.

File => New Project => Installed => Templates :::: Doesn't list f# as a category.

Websharper.vsix says it installed fine. Extension is already installed.

Repairing the install of F# tools 3.1.1 doesn't fix it.

Starting a new f# project based on an online template results in an error:  "The project creation was not successull.  Exception from HRESULT:0x80041FE1  "

Is there a way of checking in visual studio web express 2013 that the f# tools have successfully been installed?

The f# tool chain is working in VS express for windows desktop.

Comment: I've tried 3.1.2 and it works. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sub>Reposting from comment, as wiki since it was only a guess:</sub>

Try [3.1.2](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/fsharpteam/archive/2014/08/20/announcing-the-release-of-visual-f-tools-3-1-2.aspx), which only came out last Wednesday – it may contain bug fixes that resolve your issue.